# If there is an embedding from K to the p-adic numbers then p splits in K

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am reading Serge Lang's book on elliptic functions, chapter 13, and this came up:

let $k$ be a quadratic number field given with an embedding $k \rightarrow Q_p$. Then $p$ splits in $k$.

I dont understand where this comes from

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Outline:** $K\hookrightarrow\mathbb Q_p$ then in particular $\mathcal O_K\subseteq \mathbb Z_p$. Now the kernel of the composition $\mathcal O_K\hookrightarrow\mathbb Z_p\to \mathbb F_p$ is a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $\mathcal O_K$ dividing $(p)$. Checking $\mathfrak p\ne(p)$ is equivalent to checking $\mathcal O_K/p\ne\mathbb F_p$. But that's true since $\mathcal O_K$ is a free abelian group of rank $2$.

(Please fill in the details yourself!)

Comment: thanks! that clears it up

Comment: could you explain why the prime in K does not ramify?

Comment: You can work out the details, but it corresponds to the fact that there are two distinct embeddings $K\hookrightarrow\mathbb Q_p$, which give rise to two distinct prime ideals $\mathfrak p_1$ and $\mathfrak p_2$.